# Draw objects in back of activity

Tags: android, xml, draw

I have an activity where i'd like to draw some blocks dinamically in the back. Without overlaying the current menu.

[image]

This is the actual menu. Blocks should be drawn in the back without covering the buttons menu.
I already have the shapes of the blocks in an xml file.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you use RelativeLayout and put the blocks in the begining they won't cover it.

Comment: Buttons are already in the relative, besides. Its supposed to be dinamic, the blocks should generate at random.